# How to resolve Mongoose Connect UNKNOWN?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a REST API service with Node, Express and MongoDB. I installed MongoDB and it runs normally on my PC on localhost:27017. I can add collections and read them. In my app.js file I have this setup

```js
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/bookAPI');
    
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log("h");
});
    
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api.js'));
    
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Running on port ' + port);
});
```

I always get an error- `MongoError - cannot connect UNKNOWN`.
I've searched for hours and didn't find any solution. How can I fix it so it can connect to MongoDB, which is working properly...?

Comment: Do you have the mongod instance running on the same machine?
Also, try mongodb://localhost:27017/bookAPI

Comment: I do have mongod running and also inserted some dummy data. I tested the same instanse on a different PC with Win7 installed and it worked. I found out later that XP is not supported by mongodb in the new releases.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, with installing stable mongoose.
It was mongoose 4.x, I've installed 3.8 (npm install mongoose@3.8.*) in winxp.

Answer (score 1):

```
const dbpath = "mongodb+srv://127.0.0.1/bookAPI";

// Data connection
mongoose.connect(dbpath, {user: 'username', pass: 'password', useUnifiedTopology: true , useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(()=> console.log("Now connected to MongoDB!"))
  .catch(err=> console.error("Something went wrong", err));
```

I was using Compass and this piece of code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Found the issue!  Mongoose docs have you put the username and password into the dbpath, adding them into options worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to change:**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/bookAPI')

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log("h");
});
```

**Into:**

```
var appConnection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/bookAPI');

appConnection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
appConnection.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log("h");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://" + host + ":" + dport + "/" + dbName;
mongoose.connect(connectionString, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to database ' +dbName);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/bookAPI');`